# You have reached your pull request limit Docker

Tags: docker

We are getting toomanyrequest: You have reached your pull request limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading

Error while executing command docker build -- tag Reason: exit status 1

Any alternative to resolve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQ6O.png)

Comment: are you using some comercial cicd system?

Answer (score 2):

The rate limits of 100 container image requests per six hours for anonymous usage, and 200 container image requests per six hours for free Docker accounts are now in effect. Image requests exceeding these limits will be denied until the six hour window elapses.

for more insight check this [link](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits)

Answer (score 0):

before use `docker pull`, login to `docker-hub` with your username and password as bellow.

```
docker login
```

then insert your username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your own docker repository using https://hub.docker.com/_/registry and then you can cache through your own registry if you are pulling the same images many times.

Only if the cache does not have the image does it get it from DockerHub.

Details here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/